# Navigating a returned object

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

In PHP I have a multidimensional object created from looping through a list of ids

```
 $summary = array();
 foreach ( $request->id as $id ) {
 ...
 $summary[] = $summary_data;
 }
```

it's then passed to my javascript.

```
 return json_encode(array('summary' => $summary));
```

Not sure how to navigate the returned object correctly. Do I have to use the original list of id's, and use that as an index against this object? Or is there a better way to keep track of this?

End result, I want a select box such that when a new item is selected, its data is displayed.

Comment: Might help to add a sample of your JSON output.

Comment: can you provide a detailed structure of your datas? I'll try with a general structure answer anyways...

Comment: The structure will be the same as your associative array. If you're unsure, `console.log` it and you can see the structure for yourself and find out how to traverse it.

Comment: There's no way of telling what your data looks like. You're only showing us that `$summary_data` is pushed into an array, and then encoded en returned. But what is actually in it? What are you trying to do... what, who, where, why, when?

Answer (score 1):

A general JSON object would look like this (trying to put all possible cases):

```
{
    "key1":"value1", 
    "subObject":{
        "subKey1":"subValue1",
        "subKey2":"subValue2"
    },
    "arrayOfSubObjects":[
        {"subKey3":"subValue3"},
        {"subKey4":"subValue4"}
    ]
}
```

You can reference any element of a JSON object with jsonObject.key, but remember those part between [] are arrays so you'll need to index them as if they were in an array so:

```
// to point subKey1:

jsonObject.subObject.subKey1;

// to point subKey3

jsonObject.arrayOfSubObjects[0].subKey3;

OR

// to point subKey1:

jsonObject["subObject"]["subKey1"];

// to point subKey3

jsonObject["arrayOfSubObjects"][0]["subKey3"];
```

note the 0 has no quotes because it's an index.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Keys are strings.

Comment: yea sorry I was still finishing my answer